# Symfony: Al cambiar la variable de entorno APP_ENV=prod el proyecto deja de funcionar

Tags: symfony4

Al momento de pasar a un entorno de producción el proyecto deja de funcionar, al limpiar la cache me sale un error que no encuentra mis clases de formulario, compruebo que las rutas estén bien y no hay problemas, ejecute: composer dump-autoload para actualizar el autoload y este no me arroja ningún error, ¿alguna idea de cuál pueda ser el problema? de ante mano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno nosé porque motivo, pero para solucionarlo bastó con volver a crear la clase que no encontraba, limpié la cache y actualicé el autoload con composer, ahora ya carga el proyecto.